# problem with getting data from internet with POST request with [r]

Tags: r, post, httr

I'm trying to get data from a website with R. the request headers in XHR is like this:

```
Request URL: https://bi.cbi.ir/api/chartdata/getdata
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 217.218.78.58:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 326
Content-Type: application/json
Cookie: __RequestVerificationToken=iovG1l3F2bEukN-w7nW9rNQgFpLycTL97dHE1g9_1TOcBimWnEINskcLJb3x7o2hEW0lAIvCoNUxN_Cni5yXM0y6rcHodI-5F5D_VdASLK41; TS01b59e8b_26=015d206c4e850b3e83509f364e3b142c2ff9966cc6a8f8d7696b945890cc80ccfa34119c8c8124c953ff000e440573581fe35b5fb21d2dcfeffda6a9691776067e01988db7; sadaf-dashboard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b59e8b=01bbddaca76a050c42989f8ce88d78ff5ba36d939a1a9ddf718ac942b376602b646c92cae599f170b289e745e04b27b051bb8aa9904ca0ded7d2316d875316050458b8ff1aed95d0f42929204904a42c2fed1c954c
Host: bi.cbi.ir
Origin: https://bi.cbi.ir
Referer: https://bi.cbi.ir/sadaf/dashboard/YKDhOQJC5nS3
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

I use this code to get the data (with package httr):

```
p=POST("https://bi.cbi.ir/api/chartdata/getdata" , encode = c("multipart", "form", "json", "raw"))
```

but it seems something is wrong. first:

```
   p$status_code
500
```

but I guess it should be 200 (regarding info in header requests).
and second:

```
content(p, 'parse')
```

doesn't show me the data.

I guess the problem is with encoding part. the Accept-Encoding of the site is (gzip, deflate, br) but the POST command in R has this encoding options :
("multipart", "form", "json", "raw")

What is the problem? what I've done wrong?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I think a first course of action is to review the `httr` vignettes and then to look carefully at the help page for `POST` since you're not supplying the `encode` parameter correctly (and this also suggests you might be super-new to R in general). You're also confusing body parameter encoding with HTTP transfer encoding, so brushing up on HTTP fundamentals might be good as well. This also looks like you're trying to replicate a web request using `httr`. The [`curlconverter` ](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/curlconverter) might be a good thing to look into if so.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I am pretty new to R. But I also singled out encoding options like for example p=POST("https://bi.cbi.ir/api/chartdata/getdata" , encode = "json") or also other options but the result was not different. yes, it seems that I confused encode option of POST in R with Accept-Encoding. but what is your suggestion?

Comment: I gave you many suggestions. SO is not a tutorial site. There's a great deal abt what you are doing that you do not have basic familiarity with.